# After a crash figures references are in italian

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I am writing a thesis using word 2010. 
Till now each figure had an automatic number reference starting with "Figure x" where x is an auto incrmeneting number.

After a crash from next figure on I get "FigurA 1", so not only the language has become italian but the index got corrupted as well.

Is there a way to fix this? I think the fact the index corrupted may be simply due to the change of language...or at least I hope so.